# Apollo weirdly alters the query result

Tags: javascript, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using `react-apollo`s Query-Component in React Native to get data from my backend.

The result looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'US Election',
    parties: [
      {
        name: 'democrats',
        id: 4,
        pivot: {
          id: 3,
          answers: [
            {
              id: 13,
              question_id: 3,
              reason: 'Lorem ipsum',
              __typename: "Answer"
            },
            {
              id: 14,
              question_id: 5,
              reason: 'Lorem ipsum',
              __typename: "Answer"
            },
          ],
          __typename: "ElectionPartyPivot"
        },
        __typename: "Party"
      },
    ],
    __typename: "Election"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Another one',
    parties: [
      {
        name: 'democrats',
        id: 4,
        pivot: {
          id: 7,
          answers: [
            {
              id: 15,
              question_id: 7,
              reason: 'Lorem ipsum',
              __typename: "Answer"
            },
            {
              id: 18,
              question_id: 9,
              reason: 'Lorem ipsum',
              __typename: "Answer"
            },
          ],
          __typename: "ElectionPartyPivot"
        },
        __typename: "Party"
      },
    ],
    __typename: "Election"
  }
]
```

Now, when I `console.log` the result, the second election *"Another one"* has the `pivot` from the first entry `US Election`.

I think this is because of the normalization that goes on within Apollo (Cause the ID of the parties are the same in both) but I'm unsure how to fix it, so that it does not normalize this or normalizes it correctly.

EDIT

I came up with this solution, but it looks hacky. I now get the election_id together with the party and create a different Identifier within the cache. I wonder if this is good practice?

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: object => {
    switch (object.__typename) {
      case 'Party': return `${object.election_id}:${object.id}`;
      default: return defaultDataIdFromObject(object);
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: config.apiUrl,
  cache
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, providing a custom `dataIdFromObject` would be necessary in this case. You should consider using `Party:${object.election_id}:${object.id}` as the key in case there are other `Election` fields in the future that will require the same treatment.

This is, at the root, an issue with the way the schema is designed. There's an underlying assumption in GraphQL that while the nodes in your GraphQL may have relationships with one another, they are fully independent of each other as well. That is to say, within the same context, the same node should not represent different data based on the presence or absence of other nodes in the response.

Unfortunately, that's exactly how this response is structured -- we have a node that represents a `Party`, but its fields are different depending on its relationship to another node -- the `Election`.

There's two ways to remedy this sort of issue. One way would be to maintain different instances of each `Party` with different ids for each `Election`. Rather than representing a political party over the course of its life, the underlying data model behind the `Party` type would present a political party only in the context of one election.

The other way would be to restructure your schema to more accurately represent the relationships between the nodes. For example, a schema that supported this kind of query:

```
{
  elections {
    id
    name
    parties {
      id
      name
      # omit pivot field on Party type
    }
    # instead because pivots are related directly to elections, add this field
    pivots {
      id
      answers
      # because we may still care what party the pivot is associated with as well
      # we can add a party field to pivot to show that relationship
      party {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed and fantastic explanation. I guess I have to start to think a little different about my data structure in GraphQL compared to what I used to before!